# spring application not taking bean from configuration class

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin

I have a spring boot 2.5.x application written in kotlin. I have flowwing class definations in it

```
@Component
class MyExecutor<INPUT_TYPE,OUTPUT_TYPE>(@Value("xyz") val myVar: String){
    fun execute(INPUT_TYPE): OUTPUT_TYPE {// implementation}
}
```

I need a more than one instance of this bean one with default myVar as "xyz" and other with the myVar I provide explicitly say "abc". For this I defined a configuration class

```
@Configuration
class AppConfig{
   
  @Bean
  fun customExecutor(){
     return MyExecutor<TypeA,TypeB>("abc")
  }
}
```

Next I need to use this in my service. So I have two service where different implementation of this executor is required to be injected.

```
@Service
class ServiceA(
   @Qualifier("customExecutor") val customExecutor: MyExecutor<TypeA,TypeB>
){ ... }
```

And a another service class

```
@Service
class ServiceB(
   val executor: MyExecutor<TypeC,TypeD>
){ ... }
```

When I run application with this config the application fails to run with exception saying

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Field customExecutor in pkg.ServiceA required a bean of type 'pkg.MyExecutor' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'pkg.MyExecutor' in your configuration.
```

On removing `@Qualifier` annotation server successfully starts but ServiceA is loaded with default MyExecutor with myVar as "xyz" rather than "abc"

Is there a way to achieve a solution where ServiceA gets loaded with MyExcutor("xyz") and ServiceB gets loaded with MyExecutor("abc").

**Edit:**

After removing `@Component` from `MyExecutor` the classes looks something like below

```
    class MyExecutor<INPUT_TYPE,OUTPUT_TYPE>(val myVar: String){
        fun execute(INPUT_TYPE): OUTPUT_TYPE {// implementation}
    }
```

```
@Configuration 
class AppConfig{       
   @Bean("customExecutor")   
   fun customExecutor(){      
      return MyExecutor<TypeA,TypeB>("abc")   
   }         

   @Bean("defaultExecutor")   
   fun defaultExecutor(){      
      return MyExecutor<TypeC,TypeD>("xyz")   
   }  
}
```

```
@Service
class ServiceA(
   @Qualifier("customExecutor") val customExecutor: MyExecutor<TypeA,TypeB>
){ ... }
```

And a another service class

```
@Service
class ServiceB(
   @Qualifier("defaultExecutor") val executor: MyExecutor<TypeC,TypeD>
){ ... }
```

Comment: Your confiugration only creates one, so it complains about the other.

Comment: Doesn't look like an issue of duplicate bean to me. when try to do debugging. the debugger hits initialisation in ServiceA class first and then the configuration class. which means when the ServiceA needs the bean till that time Bean has not been instantiated in Configuration class. In fact in case when server fails to start the debugger in configuration class does not hit and application fails to start before that.

Comment: I doubt that your configuration is actually being loaded at all (make sure it is in a convered package) and you will need 2 instances as both services require a different instance.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have a debugger point inside AppConfig inside function `customExecutor` on return line. if configuration class is creating bean of type `MyExecutor<TypeA,TypeB>` debugger should have hit this line but thats not the case. still to my understanding you are suggesting to have config class like this `@Configuration
class AppConfig{
   
  @Bean
  fun customExecutor(){
     return MyExecutor<TypeA,TypeB>("abc")
  }         @Bean
  fun defaultExecutor(){
     return MyExecutor<TypeC,TypeD>("xyz")
  } 
}` . I'll try that as well.

Comment: As I stated **I  doubt that your configuration is actually being loaded**. Which is what your debugging actually confirms. So you have this in a package that isn't covered by the component scanning of Spring Boot.

Comment: If you look at the error, its not complaining about the other but the first one itself. Also, as mentioned in the details itself, if I remove `@Qualifier` I can see the debugger hitting config class. which suggest spring is able to load the configuration class but its not using the same bean in ServiceA class rather the default one.

Comment: Sigh. Please read. I stated your configuration doesn't kick in, which lets the service fail because of the `@Qualifier`. There is also an instance created due to the `@Component` which will be used for everything else (I would suggest to remove it and then it will all break down as you now need to explicitly need to configure all needed instances in your `@Configuration` class).

Comment: Tried it. removed `@Component` and `@Value` from `MyExecutor`. Inside `MyConfig` created 2 bean  (one for `MyExecutor<TypeA,TypeB>("abc")` and another for `MyExecutor<TypeC,TypeD>("xyz")`) instantiated using their respective qualifier in their respective service class. still getting the same exception

Comment: Which is, as I stated 3 times before, because your `@Configuation` class isn't being picked up, thus no beans, thus nothing to inject, hence the exception.

Comment: so, my root package is say `x.y.z` and my config class is inside say `x.y.z.config.MyConfig` and my Main class full qualified path looks like `x.y.z.MyApplication`. How should I make sure that the configuration class is getting picked up?

Comment: Also, there are other config files in the config package which is getting loaded properly.

Comment: By default it should, apparently there is something in your app that prevents this.

Comment: How you are defining the 2 beans in the configuration file? (as you mentioned in the comment above where you removed the @Component from MyExecutor)

Comment: @FelipeBonfante update in the description itself.

Comment: Thanks! Can you try to add the @Primary in the defaultExecutor bean and see if it works?

Comment: Tried Already, No use.